# PDOException: Data based on DATE from TIMESTAMP column

Tags: mysql, pdo

Not so sure why this doesn't work. I read many post and I still can't make it work.

Can I use "to_char" within a prepared statement?

```
    global $db;
    $st = $db->prepare("SELECT * 
                        FROM info
                        WHERE To_char(timestampColumn, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '$NewDateToQuery' 
                        ORDER BY timestampColumn DESC");

    $st->execute();
```

This is something very simple - select from a timestamp column based on the date (I am using jQuery UI datepicker to select the date).

Any help is greatly appreciated. Sorry that this will appear as perhaps a duplicate... I have read the other post and all the ones suggested when started the quetions. However, I could not get the answer.

Best,

**UPDATE**

Currently $NewDateToQuery looks YYYY-MM-DD. If I added the acual hour:minutes:seconds of a known record in my table, it does return the correct information. 
Should I split the timestamp column into 2 columns (1 for date and another for time)? I don't think that would be the most efficient way.

Thanks again.

Comment: Is your column a Unix timestamp or Y-d-m H:I:s? And what is the format you are using for your date picker?

Comment: Y-d-m H:I:s. For the format I have it as YYYY-MM-DD just as the dates appear in my timestamp column.

Answer (score 0):

why use To_char in where

try this

```
$st = $db->prepare("SELECT date_format(`timestampColumn`, '%Y-%m-%d')  as myDate
                        FROM info
                        WHERE timestampColumn= '$NewDateToQuery' 
                        ORDER BY timestampColumn DESC");
```

Comment: to_char continues to throw the error "Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION la_macarena.To_char does not exist'

Answer (score 0):

**It was beyond simple... sadly it took me all day to make it work.**
Here it goes if you need to select a particular day from a timestamp column.

Just wrap the column to query conditionally by DATE(). See below. $NewDateToQuery is a string in the following format YYYY-MM-DD.

$st = $db->prepare("SELECT timestampColumn
                        FROM info
                        WHERE DATE(timestampColumn) = '$NewDateToQuery' 
                        ORDER BY timestampColumn DESC");